# With an Azure DevOps shared deployment group, web apps are being overwritten, how can one best debug this?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-server

### The Context

I have an [on-prem TFS (Azure DevOps) server (version 2018.2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/provide-feedback?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server) with a single [deployment agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#deploy-agents-to-a-deployment-group) installed.

This agent is in a [shared deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#share-a-deployment-group) and is used to deploy multiple IIS web applications, each application residing in its own project and release pipeline.

The release pipelines all use an identical flow, running the [IIS Web App Deployment](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md) module to deploy each application.

In the [deployment parameters](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md#parameters-of-the-task) each application has its own, unique `virtual application` specified.

### The Problem

When one application is deployed, it correctly deploys to its unique virtual application, *but* all other virtual applications that the agent is configured to deploy *even in other release pipelines* get overwritten by the one application.

### What I have tried

1. Verified that each `virtual application` parameter is, in fact, unique in the configs
2. Verified that the release deployment logs for any given deployment do not mention any *extra* deployment paths. This is particularly perplexing, because the logs *say* that the operation correctly deploys to *only one* virtual application.
3. Check for any strange IIS logs on the target server

### The Question

What are the best next steps for debugging an Azure DevOps issue like this? This is an *on-prem* server, so I have a higher level of access than if this were cloud hosted.

I am thinking perhaps:

1. Check the agent version and update it to latest?
2. Could there be *other* logs with valuable info? On the target server? On the DevOps server?

Comment: Did you run the deployment with the `system.debug` variable set to `true`?

Comment: @DanielMann, I did, with the same results. The logs make no mention of extra deployment paths, only one virtual application is ever listed.

Comment: @David Could you share your build definition?

Comment: Thanks @CeceDong-MSFT. I solved the problem with help from an [Azure DevOps troubleshooting document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops). I will post my process as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. See the written-up process below.

## Solution

The problem was not with the deployment module, but rather I had mis-configured the [IIS management module](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0) that ran immediately preceding each deployment module. Each management module had the same `physical path` parameter value set for each virtual application, which caused each deploy to overwrite any previous deploy.

## Debugging Process

When writing up a corresponding issue for this on github, ironically, there was a [link to instructions for troubleshooting AzureDevops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops), so I started following that document.

1. I [turned on verbose logging on the deployment agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs) by adding the `system.debug` variable to the release pipeline and setting it to `true`.

   - From this I could see that there were, in fact, no other virtual applications being deployed to
2. I checked the additional agent logs on the target server under the agent install directory in a directory titled `_diag`.

   - This showed that everything was working correctly
3. Still not convinced, [I looked at the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/469f022c8afa18a9035a3a70f4086a35779cb436/Tasks/Common/webdeployment-common/deployusingmsdeploy.ts#L26) and found that all the module is doing is running MsDeploy.

   - This got me wondering if all the deployments were going to the same physical location
4. Then I looked at my config for the [IIS management module](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0) and noticed that I had set identical physical paths for each virtual application.
5. I tested the hypothesis by setting a different physical path for each application, and, *yay*, the applications no longer overwrote each other!